# Twitter Typeahead plugin not querying server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with Twitter's [Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) plugin for bootstrap. Typeahead is not even making an Ajax query (I can see in Chrome Development Tools that no query is happening).

Here is my Html:

```
<input type="text" id="BookSearch"/>
```

Here is my Typeahead code:

```
    $("#BookSearch").typeahead([{
        name: "google-books-search",
        remote: "/Book/GoogleBookSearch?query=%QUERY",
        template: [
            "<img src='{{SmallThumbnailImageUrl}}' />",
            '<p>{{Title}}</p>',
            '<p>{{Authors}}</p>'
        ].join(),
        engine: Handlebars
    }]);
```

I can verify that Handlebars is loaded. 
I can verify that Typeahead is being initialized AND that it is finding the BookSearch control (I stepped through the Typeahead code to see this).

However, it seems that the Typeahead code never receives any events. I put breakpoints at the Focus, Blur, and SpecialKeys (and every other event handler) and nothing is being recognized.

I have also tried commenting out the Template and Engine lines from the above code and just letting Bootstrap make a query for data it does not recognize, but that also does not work.

I can browse to the remote URL and verify that data is indeed being returned. But, again, Typeahead is not even trying.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found *AN* answer to this, but the answer doesn't make much sense to me:

In going through the bootstrap (2.3.2) code, I noticed that the code for the Typeahead plugin was ***significantly*** less than the code posted at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js. Like, almost nothing was there except for event handlers.

So I created a custom download of Boostrap that did NOT include the Typeahead plugin, and then referenced the Typeahead plugin separately in code. And not that worked.

I'm not sure why the Typeahead that was embedded in Bootstrap 2.3.2 did not work, but including Typeahead on its own solved my problem.

If I don't get a better answer than this in a couple days, I'll go ahead and accept this as an answer. But hopefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: The typeahead plugin included with Bootstrap is not really the same as the standalone one you're trying to use and they work quite differently.  It's easy to get them confused due to the names.